# How to Print the calendar for March and April 2015 and show the calendar entries side-by-side? using UNIX

Tags: cal

how to Print the calendar for March and April 2015 and show the calendar entries side-by-side? in UNIX

Answer (score 3):

This command:

```
paste <(cal 3 2015 | awk '{printf "%-20s\n",$0}') <(cal 4 2015)
```

will create this output:

```
     March 2015              April 2015
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa    Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7              1  2  3  4
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14     5  6  7  8  9 10 11
15 16 17 18 19 20 21    12 13 14 15 16 17 18
22 23 24 25 26 27 28    19 20 21 22 23 24 25
29 30 31                26 27 28 29 30
```

Note: The awk subcommand was used to have the last line of the left-side command padded correctly.

Edit: A more compact variant that makes use of a `cal` feature (option `-3`) and requires less processes could be:

```
cal -3 3 2015 | awk '{print substr($0,23)}'
```

Comment: But  `paste <(cal 3 2015) <(cal 4 2015)` works for me...

Comment: If various `cal` commands behave differently; then the variant with the `awk` padding will work in a wider context of systems. (I wonder why they "optimized" away the trailling blanks in some versions; I think it would be better to have generally a consistent line width with `cal`.)

Answer (score 1):

If your `cal` supports `-A` parameter its easy to display more months - you can display current and **one** future month like this:

```
cal -A1
```

This way you can also specify to display other than current month and year by using `-m` option, for *March 2015* it will be:

```
cal -A1 -m3 2015
```

**But** if you can't use `-A` you can combine two outputs with `pr`:

```
pr -t -m <(cal <your_params>) <(cal <your_params>)
```

or with `paste`:

```
paste <(cal <your_params>) <(cal <your_params>)
```

Comment: There is no need for any script magic here.

Comment: Depending the on the `cal` version that you have on your system the `paste` variant may require an additional formatting. (See my original answer for the working solution.)

Comment: @Janis what OS do you use? `cal -A1` works fine on my Debian.

Comment: terdon; my OS (cygwin) is as irrelevant as yours (Debian) for the answers and comments given. (Often questions like yours are followed by a "switch to the latest release" followup and ignoring the substance of the answer.) I'm of course glad your OS supports the simpler syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
cal -3| awk '{print substr($0,23)}'
```

Comment: Is there a badge for copy/pasting an answer that was already given a day ago?

Comment: @Jains - Looks like you discovered the Linux commands!!!